# Hide sectionindextitles when delete button appears on the cell

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I am setting titles for Tableview using `SectionIndexTitlesForTableview` method. When I swipe a cell, delete button appears next this titles which looks odd. How to hide this indexTitles when delete button appears and show when delete button disappears.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The `inEditMode` method hides an index when a table is going to be edited

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    [self inEditMode:YES];
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    [self inEditMode:NO];
}
//on self.editButtonItem click
-(void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated{
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    [self inEditMode:editing];
}

-(void)inEditMode:(BOOL)inEditMode{
    if (inEditMode) { //hide index while in edit mode
        self.tableView.sectionIndexMinimumDisplayRowCount = NSIntegerMax;
    }else{
         self.tableView.sectionIndexMinimumDisplayRowCount = NSIntegerMin;
    }
    [self.tableView reloadSectionIndexTitles];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This might help

```
- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [tableView isEditing] ? nil: @[@"A",@"B",@"C"];
}

- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing
{
    [super setEditing:editing];
    [self reloadSectionIndexTitles];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
        {
        _someBoolean = YES;
       [tableView reloadData];
        return YES;
        }

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
            if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
                _someBoolean = NO;
                [tableView reloadData];
            }    
        }


- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
        {
                return _someBoolean ? nil : _yourTitlesArray;
        }
```